# Why does the NWT capitalize "YOU" in many verses?

Tags: bible-translation, jehovahs-witnesses, nwt

Throughout many passages in the NWT (Jehovah's Witness specific *New World Translation*), all instances of the pronoun "you" are written in all capitals. Here is an example from [Acts 2:38](https://www.jw.org/en/library/bible/bi12/books/acts/2/#v44002038):

> Peter [said] to them: “Repent, and let each one of ​YOU​ be baptized in the name of Jesus Christ for forgiveness of ​YOUR​ sins, and ​YOU​ will receive the free gift of the holy spirit.

What is the reasoning behind this capitalization? I am familiar with the practice of capitalizing He/Him and similar pronouns when referring to God or Christ, but this appears to be quite different and I have no idea what the rational is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The capitalized YOU is used to disambiguate singular vs. plural usage. While unclear in English, the difference between singular and plural usage is clear in the original Greek sources of these texts.

> It also makes a distinction between the singular and plural in the 2nd person personal pronoun: "you" is singular, and "YOU" is plural. In English, the word "you" is both singular and plural; in Greek, however, there is a clear distinction. The NWT has used this method to try and preserve this distinction. -- [THE NEW WORLD TRANSLATION; A Critical Analysis](http://www.zianet.com/maxey/Ver5.htm) by Al Maxey

Comment: "Y'all" might have worked too ;-)

Comment: This is actually pretty cool. I'd be neat to see the convention more widely adopted.

Comment: I find it incredibly distracting. Capital YOU generally means emphasis, "Let each one of ***you*** be baptised" (rather than ***them*** in that group over there).

Comment: I'm a big fan of "y'all."  Most languages distinguish between 2nd person singular and plural.  We down in the south just give everybody else the right word to express it in English.

Comment: It's actually in small block caps, which makes it a little less distracting. And @AffableGeek, *y'all* does not form part of my vocabulary: in the Irish midlands, we say *ye*. And in Northern Ireland, Dublin, and parts of Scotland, they say *youse*. Originally, of course, *you* was the plural form.

Comment: The 2013 edition has removed that feature.

Answer (score 3):

This feature is explained in the *Introduction* section at the front of the New World Translation. It is used to differentiate between singular and plural "you". If the subject is plural, small caps "YOU" is used.

> SECOND PERSON PLURALS: Where “YOU” is printed in small capital letters, it shows that the pronoun is plural. Also, where the plural number of a verb is not apparent, its plurality is indicated by printing it in small capital letters. If the context already clearly indicates plurality, then no special capitalization is used.
>
> https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1001060001#h=24

This feature was removed in the 2013 edition of the New World Translation.